# A good translation for "backstory" of a character?

Tags: перевод

What would be a good translation of the word "backstory," specifically when talking about a character in literature? I was thinking `предыстория` but I'm not sure if it has the right connotations.

Comment: And what connotations "backstory" has?

Answer (score 5):

Actualy, предыстория is absolutely fine here. Literally предыстория is something that is before a story (or history). And I cannot remember any connotations that could make it not suitable here.

Answer (score 4):

***Предыстория*** is usually referred to events, not biographies. Here I would suggest something like

***прошлое героя***  (is interchangeable with the other two, ***герой*** can be used for shows and literature)

***история персонажа*** (is interchangeable with the other two, ***персонаж*** can be used for shows and for literature)

***биография действующего лица*** (interchangeable with the previous two and less common, ***действующее лицо*** can be used for shows only).

Comment: *персонаж* can perfectly be (and is) used to convey the meaning of "movie character"

Comment: Seems like you are right here